# How can I access Qt's used border color for use in qtstylesheets widget styling (via QPalette)?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qpalette

I can use different colors used in a Qt application via `QPalette` to style widgets via qtstylesheets, e. g. something like `background-color: palette(base)`. However, I didn't find the color used for drawing the border of some widgets like `QGroupBox` or `QFrame`.

It it possible to access this color (via `QPalette`?) as well for use in qtstylesheets widget styling?

Comment: Strange! According to the source code, it should be `QPalette::WindowText`, but it does not work.

Comment: windowText represents the foreground/text color iirc

Comment: `QFrame::paintEvent` calls [`QFrame::drawFrame`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qframe.cpp.html#_ZN6QFrame9drawFrameEP8QPainter), where [`QCommonStyle::drawControl`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/styles/qcommonstyle.cpp.html#2352) is called with `QStyle::CE_ShapedFrame` as `element`. There we have `QPalette::ColorRole foregroundRole = QPalette::WindowText;`. Furthermore, the `QFrame::StyledPanel` case calls [`QCommonStyle::drawPrimitive`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/styles/qcommonstyle.cpp.html#274) with `QStyle::PE_Frame` as `pe`. ...

Comment: ... There we have a call to `QCommonStyle::qDrawPlainRect` with `frame->palette.windowText().color()` as color.

Comment: The border color is definitely not the window text color though … e. g. using Breeze, the window text is black, and the borders are gray …

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: groupBox->setStyleSheet("QGroupBox {"
                                "background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #E0E0E0, stop: 1 #FFFFFF);"
                                "border: 2px solid gray;"
                                "border-radius: 5px;"
                                "margin-top: 10ex;"
                                "}"
                                "QGroupBox::title {"
                                "subcontrol-origin: margin;"
                                "padding: 5 0px;"
                                "}");

Comment: @user6528273 Linux, Windows and macOS ;-) It's a cross-platform project.

Comment: In short, `QFrame` delegates the painting of its frame to a subclass of `QStyle`, which is different for each OS. Take a look at those suclasses and try to find how `QStyle::CE_ShapedFrame` is painted.

Comment: So, to answer the question: It's not a single color, but may be a more compilcated procedure and it's different for different OSs? And thus not possible as such?